# A $\triangle {ABC}$ is rotated in its own plane about point $A$ into position $A'B'C'$.if $AC$ bisects $BB'$ prove that $AB'$ bisects $CC'$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-transformation

The question is :-

> A  $\triangle {ABC}$ is rotated in its own plane about point $A$ into position $A'B'C'$.if $AC$ bisects $BB'$ prove that $AB'$ bisects $CC'$

To be clear the main problem is I cant imagine how the figure will be formed .

So please tell the actual figure for the above question so that I could proceed further .

Comment: My answer was not for a general case for my misunderstanding. I am sorry for that. I edited my answer according to the feedback given. I am writing this as a comment to notify you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** (According to Michal Adamaszek's correction) Here is a general figure. You can use congruence of $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta AB'C'$ to prove the statement.

[image]

If this one was not enough:

> A kite should finish the proof.

Comment: The statement $AC$ bisects $BB'$ does not imply that $A$ must lie on $BB'$. It just means that the segment $AC$ cuts $BB'$ in half. So the picture can be much more general, but the result is still true.

Comment: That's a good point. I should edit my answer accordingly. Sorry for my misunderstanding.